# Posting a link to our page on facebook doesn't resolve correctly within FB

Tags: web-development, javascript, facebook

We have a product page, there is a javascript popup that requires users to enter an email address to gain access. But the page behind the popup is fully rendered (for SEO value and such).

https://www.frugg.com/bags/deal/32/coach-hot-lime-summer-bag

But when I try to share this page in facebook (paste it into a status update) facebook tries to reference our FB fan page: http://www.facebook.com/frugg. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't handle the link like normal (e.g. a picture to the product and linking to our website).

Here's what facebook shows as the link when I paste that above URL into a FB status update.

```
 Frugg - Las Vegas, NV - Website | Facebook
 https://www.facebook.com/frugg
 Frugg, Las Vegas, NV. 39,522 likes · 4 talking about this · 19 were here
```

Any ideas where to look? The only guess I have is that the javascript popup is interfering, but I wouldn't imagine that the FB crawler cares about javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, in our template we had the facebook open graph meta data configured as:

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/frugg" />
```

This was causing the issue.